# AES with CBC Mode Block Cipher

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

class CryptAES {
  static final String cipher_type = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key  = args[0];
    String iv   = args[1];
    String data = args[2];

    byte[] enc = encode(key, iv, data.getBytes());
    byte[] dec = decode(key, iv, enc);

    for (int i = 0; i < enc.length; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%02x", enc[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
        
    System.out.println(new String(dec));
  }

  public static byte[] encode(String skey, String iv, byte[] data) {
    return process(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, iv, data);
  }

  public static byte[] decode(String skey, String iv, byte[] data) {
    return process(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, iv, data);
  }

  private static byte[] process(int mode, String skey, String iv, byte[] data) {
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(), "AES");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec param = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
    try {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipher_type);
      cipher.init(mode, key, param);
      return cipher.doFinal(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

}
```

exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception index out of bounds for length 0[image]

exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception index out of bounds for length 0

Comment: This application requires that you provide 3 arguments - a key, an IV, and data. You give none, thus, `args[0]`, referring to 'the first argument', throws an exception - there _is no_ first argument.

Answer (score 0):

As @rzwitserloot pointed out, you need to check if there have been arguments passed into the application in the command line.

You should always be checking for null/empty/invalid values when a user can give input. A simple example on how to prevent the original error and throw a more meaningful error is below:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (null == args || args.length != 3) {
        throw new IOException("Please add arguments key, iv and data");
    }
    String key  = args[0];
    String iv   = args[1];
    String data = args[2];
    ...
}
```

You may want to be able to not have any inputs, or only input 1/2 out of the 3 arguments. For that you need to check if the argument value exists and then access it.